# firebase TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'session' and 'build_headers'

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

I am just starting to learn python and firebase. I want to set a listener to a node in firebase. the node is in

https://database.firebaseio.com/NSN

so I was looking through this tutorial

https://github.com/firebase/EventSource-Examples/blob/master/python/chat.py

based on the above tutorial I came up with this code

```
URL ="https://database.firebaseio.com/Missing NSN.json"


class ClosableSSEClient(SSEClient):
    """
    Hack in some closing functionality on top of the SSEClient
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.should_connect = True
        super(ClosableSSEClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _connect(self):
        if self.should_connect:
            super(ClosableSSEClient, self)._connect()
        else:
            raise StopIteration()

    def close(self):
        self.should_connect = False
        self.retry = 0
        # HACK: dig through the sseclient library to the requests library down to the underlying socket.
        # then close that to raise an exception to get out of streaming. I should probably file an issue w/ the
        # requests library to make this easier
        self.resp.raw._fp.fp._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.resp.raw._fp.fp._sock.close()


    self.sse = ClosableSSEClient(URL)
    for msg in self.sse:
        msg_data = json.loads(msg.data)
        if msg_data is None:    # keep-alives
           continue
           path = msg_data['path']
           data = msg_data['data']
           if path == '/':
           # initial update
              if data:
                  keys = data.keys()
                  keys.sort()
                  print(keys)
                  for k in keys:
                      self.message_queue.put(data[k])
           else:
               self.message_queue.put(data)
```

when i run this script i get this error

```
>>  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "NSNListener.py", line 96, in <module>
self.sse = ClosableSSEClient(URL)
File "NSNListener.py", line 78, in __init__
super(ClosableSSEClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'session' and 'build_headers'   
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'session' and 'build_headers'
```

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Comment: i think your code has some variable scoping issues, specifically the code after (and including):
    self.sse = ClosableSSEClient(URL)

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the traceback

Comment: Well, the solution would require reading the constructor  of the SSEClient class. I don't know what session and build_headers refer to, but positional arguments would need you need to add them with the URL

Comment: Anyways, what's the goal here? The Python admin sdk can query Firebase database

Comment: @cricket_007 I want to add a listener to a node using python and I have not be able to figure it out.

Comment: I see. And you need raw sockets for that? Firebase has an official python sdk, though no realtime listeners. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup There are also `pyrebase` and `python-firebase` libraries